# JaCoCo report doesn't include classes from all dependencies

Tags: java, maven, junit, jacoco, junit-jupiter

I have a multimodule Maven project. Root pom.xml looks like following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
    <module>...</module>
    <module>mytests</module>
</modules>
```

The pom.xml file from `mytest` module looks like this one:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-aggregate</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a.b.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>my.company.services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Obviously, the dependency `my.company.services` has other dependencies.

But when I execute from the root project the command `mvn test jacoco:report-aggregate`, the report only includes the classes from `my.company.services` module. Do not include the rest of dependencies.

Any idea about how to tell jacoco to include classes from all the dependencies?

Comment: `jacoco to include classes from all the dependencies?`. what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean to see in the html report the result of all packages form all the dependencies. Currently I'm only getting the packages from my.company.services module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modules that are added as dependencies in the mytest module will be used in the jacoco reports. So if you require coverage reports for other modules, add them to the dependency list there.

Comment: the fact is that only the dependency my.company.services is analysed. Other related dependencies of the project are not analysed. That's why I post it...

Comment: no I mean only dependencies that are explicitly specified in the dependencies section of the mytest pom.xml will be reported. If `my.company.services` has a dependency for `my.company.services2` and you need this to be reported, you need to explicitly specify this in the pom.xml's dependencies section. The dependency resolution does not do this automatically. From the pom in your question, it is not clear if you have already tried this.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works like you say. But I was asking it in case there exists any property to tell JaCoCo to resolve third dependencies... Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, no. I had to do this in the past. It's counterintuitive; but this seems to be the only way it works. Glad it worked for you as well!